# How to serialize & deserialize TimeOnly in C# and MongoDB

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

Iam using .NET 6 and TimeOnly? datatype in a C# model class. The database is MongoDB 4.4.

TimeOnly? (15:15 Hours) is saved into MongoDB as below.

```
"defaultTime" : {
    "hour" : 15,
    "minute" : 15,
    "second" : 0,
    "millisecond" : 0,
    "ticks" : NumberLong(549000000000)
}
```

But when the data is read from MongoDB, Iam getting the following exception.

```
    An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.

System.FormatException: An error occurred while deserializing the DefaultTime property of class Models.Customer: Value class System.TimeOnly cannot be deserialized.

 ---> MongoDB.Bson.BsonSerializationException: Value class System.TimeOnly cannot be deserialized.

   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer`1.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)

   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializerExtensions.Deserialize[TValue](IBsonSerializer`1 serializer, BsonDeserializationContext context)

   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.NullableSerializer`1.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)

   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.SerializerBase`1.MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializer.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)

   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializerExtensions.Deserialize(IBsonSerializer serializer, BsonDeserializationContext context)

   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer`1.DeserializeMemberValue(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonMemberMap memberMap)
```

Any help on serialization and deserialization of TimeOnly datatype ?

Update:
I chose to save ticks in MongoDB to avoid the serialization & deserialization issues as below.

```
"defaultTime" : NumberLong(549000000000)
```

Comment: There is a solution posted here for `DateOnly`: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-3717  - A similar approach should work for `TimeOnly`. I've never tried it myself, though.